# Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM and ProxyPassMatch for PHPMyAdmin, is it secure?

Tags: apache-2.4

I recently configured a Debian 8 with Apache 2.4. Since I have a fairly recent version of Apache, I used ProxyPassMatch instead of FastCgiExternalServer.

But when configuring my alias for PhpMyAdmin, I wondered if this was secure. Here's my configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my-website.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Alias /phpmyadmin/ "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>

    # Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-pma.sock|fcgi://localhost/usr/share"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

What is bothering me is the ProxyPassMatch that allows to load any file in the `/usr/share/` directory that ends with `.php*`. I only want to execute files in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` but since it's an alias the `/phpmyadmin/` part is already appended =>

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-pma.sock|fcgi://localhost/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
```

does not work, with the error that `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php` was not found.

So is my actual configuration secure enough regarding the access of `/usr/share/` ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, first it's possible to let :

`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/`

in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

But the trick is simply to create a symbolic link like that :

`ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

After, you have to execute "`systemctl reload apache2`" and it works again.